# How can I arrange only two items in horizontal in a wrap panel?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, user-controls, wrappanel

I'm using a wrap panel to show several user controls. All of the user controls have a different height and width.

I'd like to arrange the items as maximum 2 items by row, I mean:

```
| Item1 | Item2 |
| Item3 | Item4 |
| Item5 | Item5 |
```

I say this becase, when the user expand the window, the items allocate in another positions and it looks like a mess.

Comment: Did you try setting the [`.MaxWidth`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.frameworkelement.maxwidth.aspx) property?

Comment: But how MaxWidth can help me? I'll have to get the width user control and multiply for 2. Well, I'm not sure if that is possible

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `UniformGrid` it's made for this very purpose

```
<UniformGrid Columns="2">
    <!-- Your Controls.. -->
</UniformGrid>
```

Answer (score 0):

Put the WrapPanel in a ListBox, http://msmvps.com/blogs/theproblemsolver/archive/2008/11/18/some-more-fun-with-a-silverlight-listbox.aspx, and then have a MaxWidth.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do your own panel, as [here](http://forums.silverlight.net/t/35872.aspx).